# Unable to compress image in browser using my JS code

Tags: javascript, ajax, canvas, image-compression

I am unable to compress my image using JIC. I need to POST the image in compressed size jpeg so that server load is less. Actually I need the image  size at least compressed by 30%.

I have included jic.min.js but am unable to implement it. I have tried to implement compress function but to my failure It was giving error. Please help, thanks in advance.

```
 </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container p-2">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
                    mediCam
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- <iframe src="https://mediag-data.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/temp-img/WIN_20190830_00_52_59_Pro.jpg" ></iframe> -->
                    <p class="card-text">Please select images using the below button. You may also choose camera in mobile.</p>
                    <img id="myimg" height="300" width="350">
                    <input type="file" id="files" name="files" />

                    <!-- <br>
                    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded" onclick="convertToBase64()">Upload
                    </div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <!-- <label>base64:</label><br>
                    <textarea id="base64"></textarea><br>
                    <label>binary:</label><br>
                    <textarea id="binary"></textarea> -->
                    <label>Output:</label>
                    <label id="output"></label>
                    <div id="ispinner">
                            <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="spinner-border text-secondary" role="status">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="spinner-border text-success" role="status">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="spinner-border text-danger" role="status">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                                  </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>header1</th>
                            <th>header2</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>content1</td>
                            <td>content2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
                // Check for the File API support.
                //added jic.min.js
                var jic={compress:function(t,e,n){var a="image/jpeg";"undefined"!=typeof n&&"png"==n&&(a="image/png");var r=document.createElement("canvas");r.width=t.naturalWidth,r.height=t.naturalHeight;var o=(r.getContext("2d").drawImage(t,0,0),r.toDataURL(a,e/100)),s=new Image;return s.src=o,s},upload:function(t,e,n,a,r,o,s,i){void 0===XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary&&(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary=function(t){var e=Array.prototype.map.call(t,function(t){return 255&t.charCodeAt(0)});this.send(new Uint8Array(e).buffer)});var p="image/jpeg";".png"==a.substr(-4)&&(p="image/png");var u=t.src;u=u.replace("data:"+p+";base64,","");var d=new XMLHttpRequest;d.open("POST",e,!0);var c="someboundary";if(d.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary="+c),i&&"object"==typeof i)for(var f in i)d.setRequestHeader(f,i[f]);s&&s instanceof Function&&(d.upload.onprogress=function(t){t.lengthComputable&&s(t.loaded/t.total*100)}),d.sendAsBinary(["--"+c,'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="'+n+'"; filename="'+a+'"',"Content-Type: "+p,"",atob(u),"--"+c+"--"].join("\r\n")),d.onreadystatechange=function(){4==this.readyState&&(200==this.status?r(this.responseText):this.status>=400&&o&&o instanceof Function&&o(this.responseText))}}};
                //end

                if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                    document.getElementById('ispinner').style.display = "none"
                    document.getElementById('myimg').style.display = "none"
                        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
                } else {
                alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
                }


                // Found a base64 encoding to binary function online that goes something like this:


                function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                    document.getElementById('ispinner').style.display = "block"
                    document.getElementById('myimg').style.display = "none"
                    console.log("handleFileSelect")

                    //document.getElementById('base64').value = ""

                    var f = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object

                    var reader = new FileReader();


                    // Closure to capture the file information.
                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                        var binaryData = e.target.result;
                        const dt = new Date().getTime().toString();
                        const medurl = "apiaddress"+dt+".jpeg"
                        //ajax call -start

                        var saveData = $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: medurl,
                            data: f,
                            contentType:false,
                            processData:false,
                            success: function(resultData) { 
                                alert("Save Complete");
                                console.log(resultData) 
                                var getData = $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: medurl,

                                contentType:false,
                                processData:false,
                                success: function(result1) { //alert("Save Complete")
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(result1)) 
                                var resArr = result1.text.split('\n')
                                var op = ''
                                for(i=0;i<resArr.length;i++){
                                    var tmpArr = resArr[i].split(',')
                                    op = op + '<tr>'
                                    for(j=0;j<tmpArr.length;j++){
                                        op = op + ((i===0)?'<th>':'<td>') + tmpArr[j] + ((i===0)?'</th>':'</td>');
                                    }
                                    op = op + '</tr>'
                                }
                                console.log('op: '+ op)
                                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = '<table border=1>' + op + '</table>'
                                console.log(result1.text)
                                },
                                error: function(err){
                                    console.log(err)

                                }
                            });
                            },
                            error: function(err){
                                console.log(err)

                            }
                        });

                        //ajax call -end
                        console.log('Binary:');
                        console.log(binaryData)
                        //Converting Binary Data to base 64
                        var base64String = window.btoa(binaryData);
                        console.log('base64:')
                        console.log(base64String)
                    document.getElementById('ispinner').style.display = "none"
                    document.getElementById('myimg').setAttribute("src", "data:image/png;base64, "+base64String)
                    document.getElementById('myimg').style.display = "block"
                        };
                    })(f);
                    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                    // console.log('reader: ', JSON.stringify(reader))
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
                    // console.log('binary:')
                    // console.log(binString)

                }


            </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Any help would be great as I am stuck

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?  What's the error?  And, why are you using base64 for this?  Also, why use some library for this?  You could just use the Canvas API.

Comment: it was for something else base 64 .How to use canvas api

Comment: I am getting timeout error for my api if the image size is large so i want to compress the image .Couldnt we use JIC.